# Create table with column names from another tables column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have table with a single column like this:

```
---------
|  col  |
---------
|   A   |
|   B   |
|   C   |
---------
```

I want to create a new table with the following column names like this:

```
-------------------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
-------------------
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit it with the correct requirements

Comment: One way you can achieve this is using dynamic SQL ;)

Comment: You should use pivot table http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931734/6468577

Comment: which server side language your using or you want purely sql ?

Comment: @CristianAbelleira Could you implement it for me? I don't know how to do.

Comment: @jothi I want purely sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use dynamic sql.
Assuming data type int for all columns, you can do something like this:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T table
(
    col char(1)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')
```

Build the dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE TABLE YourNewTableName ('

SELECT @Sql = @Sql + col +' int,'
FROM @T 


SET @Sql = LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@Sql) - 1) +');'
--Print @sql
```

Execute it (You will probably want to print it before to make sure it's correct):

```
EXEC(@Sql)
```